# How to print elements of a nested list with different data types in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list l1 = [1, 2, 10, 9, [3, 4, 'Hello']]. I want to iterate through the nested list [3,4,'Hello'] and print each elements.

I have tried the code snippet added here. It is neither giving the output nor any error.
l1 = [1, 2, [3, 4, 'Hello']]
for i in l1:
    if type(i) == 'list':
        for j in i:
            print(j)

Comment: `type(i)` will return type object not string.

Comment: just flattern the list .>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your type check is incorrect, you're comparing a type to a string, use `isinstance` instead

```
if isinstance(i, list):
```

alternatively remove the quotes so its `list` instead of `'list'`

Comment: It is working. Thank you very much for explaining in details.

Answer (score 0):

type returns object of type class and you are comparing it to 'list' as string just change it like this:

```
l1 = [1, 2, [3, 4, 'Hello']]
for i in l1:
    if type(i) is list:
        for j in i:
            print(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    marksheet += [[name, score]]
    scorelist += [score]


scorelist = list(dict.fromkeys(scorelist))
b = sorted(scorelist)[1] 

for a, c in sorted(marksheet):
    if c == b:
        print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, 2, 10, 9, [3, 4, "Hello"]]
b = []
for i in a:
    if type(i) == type(b):
        for j in i:
            print(j)
    else:
        print(i)
```